# Calculate the rotation angle of a rectangle with respect to center

Tags: math, geometry, geolocation, trigonometry, rectangles

[image]

Say we are given a rectangle with following coordinates,
-95.3898486, 29.8421133

-95.3908478, 29.8417155

-95.3904025, 29.8409942

-95.3894423, 29.8413990

-95.3898486, 29.8421133

(plotted above)

How do we calculate by what degree rectangle is rotated with respect to the center?

Comment: Specifying a rotation center is irrelevant. All that matters is the angle. [Obtained with arctan(δy/δx) and proper sign discussion.]

Answer (score 1):

Having two neighbor vertices A and B, you can calculate direction angle of AB vector

```
alpha = atan2(B.y - A.y, B.x - A.x)
```

Also note that you can rotate rectangle both by angle `alpha` and by angle `(90-alpha)` (might be calculated for another square side).

If you work in lat/lon coordinates (not sure whether it is needed for ready projection in screen coordinates), formula is a bit more complex ([bearing here](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html)), while rough approximation might be used for some purposes

```
alpha = atan2(B.lon - A.lon, (B.lat - A.lat) / Cos(A.lon))
```

Example in Python

```
import math
A = [-95.38984863773346,29.84211329694586]
B = [-95.3894422830677,29.84139904417855]
alpha = math.atan2(B[1]-A[1], B[0]-A[0])
print(math.degrees(alpha))  #not corrected

beta = math.atan2(B[1]-A[1], (B[0]-A[0]) / math.cos(math.radians(A[1])))
print(math.degrees(beta))   #corrected by latitude squeezing


-60.36346643470065
-56.73935489918559
```

Comment: A= -95.38984863773346,29.84211329694586

B = -95.3894422830677,29.84139904417855

val alpha = Math.atan2(-95.3894422830677 - 95.38984863773346, (29.84139904417855 - 29.84211329694586)/Math.cos(-95.38984863773346))

This gives -1.5708053326809208, thinking this is in radians, it will be -90 degrees.

Can you explain how the image is rotated -90 degree?

Comment: The first argument of atan2 is y, latitude, ~29 degrees for your case, the second is x - longitude ~95. It is possible not to convert them in radians because atan2 works with y/x ratio. And  argument of cosine should be in radians. Result is about -60 degrees

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, few more questions:
1. What is not corrected and corrected in the code?
2. When we say 60 degree, which exact angle are we referring to? And in which direction?

Comment: @Suhas Nayak not corrected - without division by cos, suitable if you work in screen coordinates. Corrected - for geocoordinates. We refer to angle between OX axis and side direction, this angle depends - which side we use, what vertex is chosen as the first and what is the second. For you case seems you have to rotate rectangle by 30 degrees clockwise, so choose appropriate vertices to get reliable result (I just cannot match these long numbers with vertices)